# Plotly equivalent of ggplot's lwd

Tags: python, r, plot, ggplot2, plotly

In `ggplot()`, I can dynamically change the `lwd` variable within `aes`. However, if I use `plot_ly()` instead, this option is not available.

I am also aware of `ggplotly` to convert a ggplot to plotly, but there are issues using `geom_line()` in ggplotly, as seen in this question: [ggplotly not displaying geom_line correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36757441/ggplotly-not-displaying-geom-line-correctly)

I am currently using plotly in R, but can convert my codebase to python, if necessary.

Comment: Why the downvote/vote to close?

Comment: I know you can do that for markers by setting `marker = list(size = ...)` but I don't think its possible for lines. Atleast not like `aes` in `ggplot()`. You could hack your way around it by adding each group as a separate trace when using `plot_ly()`

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 1):

@Adam_G see below. It is hack-y of sorts so there might be a better way to do this. Someone more knowledgeable than me might be able to shed some light on this.

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)

ds <- data.frame(x = 1:100, 
                 y = sample(1:1000, size = 100), 
                 group = sample(LETTERS[1:3], size = 100, replace = T))

# Default
plot_ly(ds, x = x, y = y, group = group, mode = "lines")

# Manually change linewidth (if not too many groups)
plot_ly(ds %>% filter(group == "A"), x = x, y = y, mode = "lines", line = list(width = 2)) %>% 
  add_trace(data = ds %>% filter(group == "B"), x = x, y = y, mode = "lines", line = list(width = 5)) %>% 
  add_trace(data = ds %>% filter(group == "C"), x = x, y = y, mode = "lines", line = list(width = 10))

# In a loop (if too many groups)
p <- plot_ly()
vec <- unique(ds$group)
widths <- c(2, 5, 10)

for(i in 1:3){
  # Note that evaluate  = T is important here

  p <- add_trace(p, data = ds %>% filter(group == vec[i]), x = x, y = y, mode = "lines",
                 line = list(width = widths[i]), evaluate = T)
}

p
```